# SNMP traps and community

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap

A SNMP message is divided into two sections: a version identifier including a community name, and a Protocol Data Unit (PDU). Version identifier and community name are used for SNMP authentication. The authentication mechanism depends on the SNMP version.

An agent uses the Trap PDU to notify a manager that an event occurred. To compose Trap PDUs, an agent sets the PDU Type to 4 (Trap), fills the Enterprise ID, the agent address, the generic as well as the
specific Trap types, and additional fields as the Timestamp fields, and the Variable Bindings.

Here is my first question: when working in SNMP v2, how does the manager know the SNMP community for reading a Trap?

My second question is: When working with SNMP v3, how is the authentication mechanism implemented within a Trap manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For SNMPv2C the manager just checks that the community string extracted from incoming SNMP trap/inform matches the community name configured locally for this trap originator (source).
2. For SNMPv3 the manager needs to know the whole bunch of security parameters like security level, username, authentication/privacy protocols and passwords, context name etc in order to authenticate incoming packet and/or even decrypt it (`CBC-DES` or `CFB-AES`) if `authPriv` security level is used.

Comment: No, the community string is a part of packet header in plain text (encoded as OCTET STRING).

Comment: @Upax, in SNMP v2, the v1 TRAP PDU format is dropped, and TRAP v2 uses the command PDU format like others (GET/SET).